# Nesting comments is not allowed in C/C++. But what do the following errors mean when you try to put one comment pair inside the other?

Tags: c++, c, comments

Consider the following code from 'C++ Primer' by Lippman,

```
#include <iostream>

/*
* comment pairs /*   */ cannot nest.
* "cannot nest" is considered source code,
* as is the rest of the program
*/

int main(){
return 0;
}
```

On compiling,

```
 $cl -EHsc .\Program.cc
 Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.30.30706 for x86
 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
 
 Program.cc
 .\Program.cc(4): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not 
 support default-int
 .\Program.cc(4): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'nest'
 .\Program.cc(7): warning C4138: '*/' found outside of comment
 .\Program.cc(10): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
 .\Program.cc(10): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

Question 1:  What does the following mean from the aforementioned code in the book, ""cannot nest" is considered source code, as is the rest of the program"?

Question 2: What happens under the hood when comments are nested? What do these rather confusing errors produced by the mean?

Comment: Since there's rubbish input for the compiler it will produce rubbish errors. The compiler just don't know what to do with `cannot nest.` (which is seen as code and not comments).

Comment: It thinks `cannot` is a malformed `int cannot;`, this explains the first two errors. No idea what's the logic behind the other two.

Comment: What is unclear about the error messages? Have you searched for them?

Comment: You seem to believe there is a difference between "nesting comments" (which you are not allowed to do) and putting "one comment inside the other" (which you have done)?  They are the same thing, and pretending they are different doesn't magically convince they compiler they are different things..   The errors are because the compiler sees `cannot nest.  * "cannot nest" is considered source code,` (etc) in a context (outside a comment) where it expects valid source code, and it is not valid source code.

Comment: @Peter that's what you're inferring, I never implied that they were different. I was curious about the errors.

Comment: @dexter So once more then. What's unclear about the error messages? "missing type specifier" quite clearly says that you have omitted the type specifier when you're declaring the variable `cannot`.

Comment: @klutt it was not clear from the text I am reading, what follows when comments are nested, the behavior, just the fact that it is not allowed. The fact that /* does not start a new comment block was not specified. It was implied through, "comment pairs /*   */ cannot nest. "cannot nest" is considered source code, as is the rest of the program" nevertheless i needed a more general answer, which i got from the posted answers. Their explanation about the first two errors also helped.

Comment: Dexter: from a learning perspective, I wonder if your questions, taken as a whole, may not help you much. The odd question here or there about nuances in compiler behaviour or edge-cases are fine, but taken in sum, lots of them will just give you arcane information that isn't particularly useful if your aim is to learn C or C++.

Comment: I don't know what your learning level is, or whether you are taking a course in academic study, but things like real projects, or algorithm examples, may be far more instructive. I expect that as a general rule they will also be more on-topic here too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A comment starts with a `/*` and ends at `*/`. So in the example, the comment is

```
/*
* comment pairs /*   */
```

The fact that there is a second `/*` inside the comment does not "restart" it. It still ends an `*/`.

So then the compiler tries to interpret `cannot nest.` as source code. Its best guess seems to be that `int cannot` could have been a variable declaration, but that the `int` is missing. And then `nest` is also a bit wrong, and the errors just continue...

Answer (score 2):

Just the first occurrence of sequence `*/` ends comment block. It doesn't matter how many occurrences of `/*` are placed before (any subsequent `/*` is part of comment, not opening new block). Error depends what you have in code and may be hard to spot. In your case it finds uncommented token `cannot` which is not valid in that context.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is equivalent to this:

```
#include <iostream>

 cannot nest.
* "cannot nest" is considered source code,
* as is the rest of the program
*/

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

This is total rubbish and therefore the compiler outputs the corresponding error messages.